# SQL, select pair of rows matching on at least N columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I foun myself looking for an unusual problem with SQL.

Let's say that I have a table T1 with N columns, for simplicity named A...Z .

What I need is to find all the pairs of rows matching on at least N attributes.

Let's see a very simple example:

```
ID | A | B | C | D |
---+---+---+---+---+-
-1-| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
---+---+---+---+---+-    
-2-| 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
---+---+---+---+---+-    
-3-| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
```

In this case, with N = 2

- row 1 should be matched with row 3 (they match on columns A and B)
- row 2 has no matches
- row 3 matches with row1 because the relation is symmetric.

Do you have any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Pairs should be adjacent or could it be any pair? Like A,C?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no answer when N is a dynamic value. However, if N is given fixed, you could concat the columns first and then it's easy to retrieve the requiring data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using self-join on the table you can find number of matching values for all pairs of rows:

```
with my_table(id, a, b, c, d) as (
values
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    (2, 2, 3, 4, 1),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1)
)

select 
    t1.id, t2.id, 
    (t1.a = t2.a)::int+ (t1.b = t2.b)::int+ (t1.c = t2.c)::int+ (t1.d = t2.d)::int as matches
from my_table t1
join my_table t2 on t1.id < t2.id

 id | id | matches 
----+----+---------
  1 |  2 |       0
  1 |  3 |       2
  2 |  3 |       1
(3 rows)
```

If the number of columns is unknown you can transform the table to get arrays instead of single columns:

```
with my_table(id, a, b, c, d) as (
values
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    (2, 2, 3, 4, 1),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1)
),
my_table_transformed (id, cols) as (
    select id, array_agg(value::int)
    from my_table,
    to_jsonb(my_table) j,
    jsonb_each_text(j)
    where key <> 'id'
    group by 1
)
select *
from my_table_transformed t1

 id |   cols    
----+-----------
  1 | {1,2,3,4}
  2 | {2,3,4,1}
  3 | {1,2,2,1}
(3 rows)
```

Now you need a function to get a number of matching values in two arrays:

```
create or replace function find_matches(a1 int[], a2 int[])
returns int language sql as $$
    select sum(m)::int
    from (
        select (c1 = c2)::int as m
        from unnest(a1, a2) u(c1, c2)
    ) s
$$;
```

And use the function for the transformed table:

```
with my_table(id, a, b, c, d) as (
values
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    (2, 2, 3, 4, 1),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1)
),
my_table_transformed (id, cols) as (
    select id, array_agg(value::int)
    from my_table,
    to_jsonb(my_table) j,
    jsonb_each_text(j)
    where key <> 'id'
    group by 1
)
select t1.id, t2.id, find_matches(t1.cols, t2.cols)
from my_table_transformed t1
join my_table_transformed t2 on t1.id < t2.id;

 id | id | find_matches 
----+----+--------------
  1 |  2 |            0
  1 |  3 |            2
  2 |  3 |            1
(3 rows)
```

The last query will work for tables with different number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this. The number of fields can of course be added in the case list as requested:

```
select id1, id2, matches from
(
select
     tab1.id id1, tab2.id id2,
     (case when tab1.a=tab2.a then 1 else 0 end)+
     (case when tab2.b=tab2.b then 1 else 0 end) matches
from
           t1 tab1
cross join t1 tab2
)
where matches>1;
```

You will get the IDs of the matching rows, and the number of matching fields.